# Notation for forcing a real value between bounds

Tags: notation, real-numbers

I am simply interested in ways to write
$$
x \mapsto \min(b, \max(a, x))
$$
in a more intuitive way for some $a<b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Something like $x \mid_a^b$ but not something I invented just now.

Best one so far: $ a \lor x \land b $ thanks to HallaSurvivor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people write $a \wedge b$ for the min function, and $a \vee b$ for the max. Then the function you want would be written

$$x \mapsto a \vee x \wedge b$$

Or, even more succinctly

$$a \vee - \wedge b$$

---

I hope this helps! ^_^

Comment: I think this is an improvement, but it could be even clearer. Something like
$x \mid_a^b$

Comment: You could absolutely use that notation - just be sure to say that you're using it, because it's nonstandard. As far as I know, what I've written is the most succinct way to do it with standard notation

Answer (score 2):

How about the following? :)
$$x \mapsto \max(a, \min(b, x))$$

But seriously,
$$x \mapsto
\begin{cases}
a &\text{if $x<a$}\\
x &\text{if $a \le x \le b$}\\
b &\text{if $x>b$}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the most direct and clear way is simply to split into cases:
$$
x\mapsto\cases{a& if $x<a$\\x& if $a\leq x\leq b$\\b& if $b<x$}
$$
But it can also be done with absolute values:
$$
x\mapsto \frac{|x-a| -|x-b|}{2} +\frac{a+b}2
$$
However, this is probably not the most transparent way of writing it.