# Return $x$ if $x$ is in given bounds, otherwise return closest bound.

Tags: functions

As stated in the title, I would like to know if there is a mathematical function $f$ with only addition, division, substraction and multiplication, which would return $x$ if $x$ is in given bounds, else it would return the closest bound, for example :

$I = [-20, 20]$

If $x = 14,$ $f$ would return $14$.

If $x = 35$, $f$ would return $20$.

Does something like that exist ?

Thanks in advance for your time and help

Comment: $-20\mathbb{I}_{(-\infty, -20)} + x\mathbb{I}_{[-20,20]} + 20\mathbb{I}_{(20, \infty)}$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580975/notation-for-forcing-a-real-value-between-bounds

Comment: If your question is whether your function is *rational*, then the answer is *negative*.

Comment: To expand on metahorphy's comment, a *rational function* is a ratio of two polynomials. If you build from constants and the function $f(x) = x$, and allow any combination of additions, subtractions, multiplications and divisions, the result is always rational. Rational functions (other than the constant $0$ function) can have only a finite number of zeros, and are defined except at a finite number of points. And their derivatives are also rational. The derivative of your function is $1$ in the interval, and $0$ outside, which is not rational. Hence the function itself cannot be rational.

Comment: Wow okay I get it, thank you all for your answers