# Function that sets a maximum value of a variable and reduces its value to the maximum if it is over.

Tags: notation, computer-science

I need to know how to write some code of mine mathematically in order to make it look more elegant.
I am unfamiliar of the mathematical notation to write such a function and need some guidance.

The code I wish to translate takes the max(or min) value of a variable and reduces(or increases) its value to the maximum(or miminum) if the value is outside the bounds.
Here is the code I wish to translate into math-speak.

```
If x < 0    then     x = 0
x + 150
if x > 500  then     x = 500
```

Many thanks from a misplaced economics student!

Comment: The max and min are preset?  What happens if $x$ is *within* bounds.  Somehow you wrote that you add $150$ to it.  So that what you want to do?  but do you want to add 150 even if $x$ was below bounds:  $2\to 152;1\to 151; 0\to 150; -1,-2,-3,......., -149,-150, ....,-260, ....-536437$ all $\to 150$.  Is that actually what you want?

Comment: @fleablood yes, to clarify I want to add 150 to x after max(0,x). If x is above 0 at 5 for example the max() function will have no effect. Then 150 will be added to make it 155, and the min(155,500) will yield 500. I am confident the answer I have written below satisfies this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can project $x$ to the interval $[0,500]$ via the assignment
$$x=\min(\max(x,0),500)$$
See also [Notation for forcing a real value between bounds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580975/notation-for-forcing-a-real-value-between-bounds)

Answer (score 0):

The best i could come up with from Rob Pratt's link was

$x = (0∨x) + 150)∧ 500$

or

$x = min(max(0,x)+150,500)$